# MYSQL Timestamp Difference 48 Hours

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have the following query: SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, timestam, NOW()) AS HoursDifference

This return hour difference for example, 0, 1, 2, 3.

I need help writing a SQL Query that will take this HOUR and subtract it from 48 giving an answer of 48, 47, 46, or 45.

Let's say it gives this output:

`HoursDifference`

```
0
1
2
8
```

How can I get the following output?:

`HoursDifference`

```
48
47
46
40
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking like this

```
SELECT (48 - TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, timestam, NOW())) AS HoursDifference
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  (48 - TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, timestam, NOW())) AS HoursDifference
```